# Node.js / Heroku app crashes intermittently

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, heroku

An app I made with Node that I recently deployed to Heroku crashes frequently with this same error found in heroku logs:

2018-02-07T00:54:23.422036+00:00 app[web.1]: Request unsuccessful. Incapsula incident ID: 0-112194295413080206
2018-02-07T00:54:23.422037+00:00 app[web.1]: ^
2018-02-07T00:54:23.422039+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2018-02-07T00:54:23.422042+00:00 app[web.1]: SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0

I am not sure what the issue is. It runs fine for a while, then crashes out of nowhere. Sometimes it will crash several times in a few minutes, its very intermittent.

It looks like it might be having an issue getting a request from a url, but why is there all that html before it?

Comment: What's the app doing? Looks like it's getting invalid JSON (starting with `<` probably means it's a HTML error page) from a file or API or something that it's choking on.

Comment: Right now it is currently crashed, I can restart it manually though. Is there a reason there would be random invalid JSON?

Comment: No clue. As I said, "what's the app doing?"

Comment: Sorry, I may not be understanding. Essentially my app just gets prices from different crypto exchanges and sites and displays them all on a table. It does this with the Request package which sends a request to something like https://api.kraken.com/0/public/Ticker?pair=XBTUSD . I then use a JSON Parser to find the price I want to display.

Comment: OK, so that URL probably occasionally returns HTML (for an error page when they have an outage, I'd bet) instead of JSON. You need to handle invalid JSON.

Comment: Ah ok that explains the unexpected token < error! I will test it out!

Comment: Worked like a charm! I used Try/Catch. If it parses anything other than what it should, I give it a default value. Thanks :D